# XERO api - Filter prepayments by Contact ID

Tags: xero-api

Hi I need to fetch the [prepayments](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/prepayments) done to a particular supplier (with contact id of aa941766-b505-4c0d-ae61-16ee78ec995e) within a given date range

```
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Prepayments
```

query parameters

> where = Date >= DateTime(2019, 01, 02) && Date < DateTime(2019, 03, 12) && ContactID = "aa941766-b505-4c0d-ae61-16ee78ec995e"

I am testing in rest client. The resulting GET request

```
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Prepayments?where=Date%20%3E%3D%20DateTime(2019,%2001,%2002)%20%26%26%20Date%20%3C%20DateTime(2019,%2003,%2012)%20%26%26%20ContactID%20%3D%20%22aa941766-b505-4c0d-ae61-16ee78ec995e%22
```

But getting this 400 error response

> {
>     "ErrorNumber": 16,
>     "Type": "QueryParseException",
>     "Message": "No property or field 'ContactID' exists in type 'BankTransaction'"
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to follow the structure of the object you're expecting in the response: the ContactID property is in the Contact element of the Prepayment, so maybe try Contact.ContactID instead of just ContactID.

You also need to parse the ContactID guid for use in the where clause, like this:

```
Contact.ContactID==Guid("aa941766-b505-4c0d-ae61-16ee78ec995e")
```

Comment: I tried this and many nestings similar to that but none wored.

Comment: Updated with guid-parsing example - does that help @Viney ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.